# What are the pros and cons of using JMeterUtils.getProperty vs. __P in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm working on some JMeter test plans that employ BeanShell assertions. Within these assertions I want to acess some user properties. There are several ways to access them:

```
JMeterUtils.getProperty("propertyName")
${__P(propertyName)
props.get("propertyName")
```

Where are the differences and what are the pros and cons of each option? Are they wrapper of each other or do they have specific functionality?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally they are all exactly the same. They are even implemented the same way - they all call the `getProperty()` method on the current jmeter properties object.

The difference is where you use them.

1. The `${}` notation is used when putting variables into JMeter GUI text boxes. In the fields on the HTTP sampler for example. note that `__P` is shorthand for, and exactly the same as `__Property`
2. `props.get()` is used in beanshell scripts, without having to explicitly import `JMeterUtils`. You can also combine 1&2 to do `${__BeanShell(props.get())}`
3. If you do import `JMeterUtils` in beanshell, or you're developing a custom java class, then you would use `JMeterUtils.getProperty()`.

Of the three, I would think #1 is the most efficient because it doesn't need to instantiate and evaluate beanshell

Answer (score 1):

For Beanshell feel free to use any approach you like.

For [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language which is recommended way of doing scripting in your JMeter test - avoid refering JMeter Variables and Functions using ${this way} as it prevents script from compilation and causes execution overhead. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for more detailed explanation, different scripting approaches benchmark and scripting best practices.